# Creating Fragmented UDP Packets in C Using Libnet

Tags: c, network-programming, libnet

I need assistance in understanding how to implement fragmentation logic using Libnet for UDP packets. Despite setting the "More Fragments (MF)" flag, the packets are not being fragmented as expected.

I believe there may be issues with how I'm building the packets using Libnet. I need guidance on the correct sequence of calls and settings required to create fragmented UDP packets.

```
char payload[32];

int payload_size = 32;
memset(payload, 'A', payload_size);
libnet_build_udp(
    src_port,
    dest_port,
    LIBNET_UDP_H + payload_size,
    0,
    (unsigned char *)payload,
    payload_size,
    l,
    0
);

libnet_build_ipv4(
    LIBNET_IPV4_H + LIBNET_UDP_H + payload_size,
    0,
    255,
    htons(0x2000), //fragment flag
    128,
    IPPROTO_UDP,
    0,
    libnet_name2addr4(l, source_ip, LIBNET_RESOLVE),
    libnet_name2addr4(l, dest_ip, LIBNET_RESOLVE),
    NULL,
    0,
    l,
    0
);
```

When i set fragment flag to 0 i am able to send udp data to my server.

I've set the MF (More Fragments) flag in the IP header to indicate that more fragments are expected.
I've adjusted the payload size to exceed the Maximum Transmission Unit (MTU) of the network (e.g., 1500 bytes) to force fragmentation.
I've verified that other types of packets (TCP, UDP) can be sent successfully using Libnet.

libnet version 1.2

Comment: Are you sending the remaining fragments? The receiver won't do anything until it gets all the fragments.

Comment: Hi Barmar, i mean i cannot see packet in tcpdump too on the sender. Its like libnet somehow not building packet therefore it does not send to receiver

Comment: I'm not familiar with libnet, but I don't see any of these functions in the [documentation](https://libnet.sourceforge.net/libnet.html#Alphabetic%20List%20of%20Functions)

Comment: TCP send _segments_, UDP sends _datagrams_ (it's even in the name: User _Datagram_ Protocol), and neither fragments. IP sends packets and fragments them, and IP will reassemble the packet fragmentss before passing the data to the transport protocol (TCP or UDP).